# System call with nested calls and arguments

Tags: perl

I am attempting to use the `system` command to launch an exe that takes several arguments, including launching of more exes that also take arguments.

It is set up as follows.

`Apple.exe` takes everything as an argument.

`Box.exe` is an argument that also takes arguments.  So right now we are 2 layers in.

This is pseudocode, where the number of quotes equal the layer of arguments

```
system(Apple.exe 'Box.exe' "/candy" "/dawn" 'elf.exe' "/fence")
```

Breaking it out where everything below `Apple.exe` is passed into `Apple.exe`, there are arguments that are calls themselves. We end up with `Apple.exe` taking 5 arguments, where 2 of those arguments are calls and 3 of them are arguments for the 2 calls.

```
Apple.exe

   Box.exe /candy /dawn

   elf.exe /fence
```

Comment: Aren't you just saying that you want to run `Box.exe "/candy" "/dawn"` and `elf.exe "/fence"` and pass the results of those to `Apple.exe`?

Comment: I have .bat file that has a line: "Apple.exe" "Box.exe" /candy /dawn "elf.exe" /fence.  My goal is to emulate it using perl.  The thing is I don't know how these executables are configured.  So I am not sure if these are processed first stored and then shoved into Apple( like you suggested) or if they are all just shoved into Apple.exe and Apple deals with them.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way system calls work. When you call an executable, it gets passed a list of arguments. This is an array of strings - there is no concept of nesting other arrays in there. This is not a Perl-specific limitation; it's just how system calls work in mainstream operating systems.

One suggestion might be to call Apple.exe with two arguments:

```
system(
   "Apple.exe",
   "Box.exe /candy /dawn",
   "elf.exe /fence",
);
```

When Apple.exe receives the two arguments, it can split them on whitespace to build whatever structure it needs. If the arguments themselves may contain whitespace, choose another character to split on:

```
system(
   "Apple.exe",
   "Box.exe~/candy~/dawn",
   "elf.exe~/fence",
);
```

Alternatively, you could write out your arguments as JSON to a file:

```
[
  [ "Box.exe", "/candy", "/dawn" ],
  [ "elf.exe", "/fence" ]
]
```

And then call Apple.exe giving it the path to the JSON file:

```
system("Apple.exe", "argument-list.json");
```

Of course, whatever choice you make, you'll need to make sure that Apple.exe is programmed to receive its arguments in whatever manner that you chose to pass them.

Answer (score 0):

If this was a unix-based system, I'd say pass the information as a series of shell commands. `apple` would be called as follows:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

system(shell_quote('apple', 
   shell_quote('box', '--candy', '--dawn'),
   shell_quote('elf', '--fence'),
));
```

That generates something equivalent to

```
apple 'box --candy --dawn' 'elf --fence'
```

`apple` would look like:

```
for my $cmd (@ARGV) {
   system($cmd);   # aka system('sh', '-c', $cmd);
}
```

---

But you appear to be using Windows, and command line processing is a bit fragile in Windows. You could try

```
use Win32::ShellQuote qw( quote_cmd );

system(quote_cmd('apple', 
   quote_cmd('box', '/candy', '/dawn'),
   quote_cmd('elf', '/fence'),
));
```

which produces an ugly mess that should be equivalent to

```
apple "box /candy /dawn" "elf /fence"
```

`apple` would still look like:

```
for my $cmd (@ARGV) {
   system($cmd);   # aka system('cmd', '/x', '/c', $cmd);
}
```